# Найти количество чисел, делящихся на 3 и не делящихся на 7, 17, 19, 27 в отрезке [1016; 7937]

Tags: python

Рассматривается множество целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [1016; 7937], которые делятся на 3 и не делятся на 7, 17, 19, 27. Найдите количество таких чисел и максимальное из них.

Собственно говоря, у меня есть код:

```python
a=1016
b=7937
k=0
for n in range(a, b+1):
  if n%3 == 0 and n%7 != 0 and n%17 != 0 and n%19 != 0 and n%27 != 0:
    k+=1
print(k)
print(n)
```

Странным образом результат сходится только на половину с ответом.

Что вывела моя программа:

1568

7937

А должна была:

1568

7935

Хотелось бы услышать от знающих, где я оплошал

Comment: Найдите количество таких чисел и `максимальное из них`. - имеется в виду максимальное из чисел, которые делятся на 3 и не делятся на другие множители, а не просто максимальное число из диапазона

Comment: Вы же просто вывели b второй строкой)

Comment: Так что в итоге получилось? Интересно. Отправьте код

Answer (score 5):

Обратите внимание, что `7935` делится на три. Ожидаемый вывод содержит последнее число, удовлетворяющее условиям, а Ваш вывод - последнее проверенное число.

Comment: Хмм... Добавил print(n) в блок if сразу после k+=1. Теперь вместо одного числа у меня целая последовательность по возрастанию, зато в конце неё верный ответ <>__<>

Comment: @g1shy Проще всего запоминать  "хорошее" n:  `last_n = n` после `k+=1`

Comment: @MBo Но ведь если сначала назначить переменной lasl_n значение = 0, а потом в блоке if написать lasl_n = n после k+=1, то получится неверный ответ. (Объясните поподробней, если я неверно рассудил. Питон учу 2 недели всего лишь)

Comment: Ну в last_n же всегда будет последнее подходящее число.

Comment: Теперь разобрался: в принте забыл n заменить на last_n)) Спасибо, что помогли

Answer (score 0):

Вот правильное решение:

```python
a=1016
b=7937
k=0
last_n = 0
for n in range(a, b+1):
  if n%3 == 0 and n%7 != 0 and n%17 != 0 and n%19 != 0 and n%27 != 0:
    k+=1
    last_n = n
print(k, last_n)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
a = 1016
b = 7937
k = 0
max = 0

for n in range(a, b+1):
    if n%3 == 0 and n%7 != 0 and n%17 != 0 and n%19 != 0 and n%27 != 0:
        k += 1
        if max < n:
            max = n
            
print(k)
print(n)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В вашем коде повторяется ошибка ТС.