# Числа принадлежащие отрезку [7525; 13486], которые делятся на 7 и не делятся на 6, 9, 14, 21. Найдите количество таких чисел и минимальное из них

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, как будет выглядеть программа для нахождения минимального числа на python.
С максимальным я разобрался, а вот с минимальным не получается.
вот сама задача:
Рассматривается множество целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [7525; 13486], которые делятся на 7 и не делятся на 6, 9, 14, 21. Найдите количество таких чисел и минимальное из них. В ответе запишите два целых числа без пробелов и других дополнительных символов: сначала количество, затем минимальное число
Вот та выглядит программа для максимального числа

```py
a = 0
m = 0
for i in range (7525,13486+1):
    if i%7==0 and i%6!=6 and i%9!=0 and i%14!=0 and i%21!=0:
        a = a + 1
        m = i
print (a,m)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где нужно исправить, чтоб получилась программа для минимального значения

Comment: Ну попробуйте же сами ее написать. Мы в случае неудачи поправим, но просто так писать за вас даже такую программу никто не будет.

Comment: Тем более, что для максимального числа, она уже у вас готова, как я понимаю. Если вы не извращались слишком сильно, то там нужно всего лишь заменить либо max() на min(), либо < на >.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Найти количество чисел, делящихся на 3 и не делящихся на 7, 17, 19, 27 в отрезке \[1016; 7937\]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1192528/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-3-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-7-17-19-27-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: EzikBro, я извиняюсь, забыл выложить код

Comment: Если вы хотите именно разобраться, то заходите в чат и я постараюсь вам помочь: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116385/q1206545

Comment: Если искать между 7525 и 7525, то понятно, что ничего не найдёшь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавим проверку, что значение минимума уже заполнено.
Условия можно упростить.

```
a = 0
mn = 0
for i in range (7525,13486+1):
    if i%7==0 and i%2>0 and i%3>0:
        a = a + 1
        if (mn==0):
            mn = i   
print (a,mn)
```

Comment: @Кирилл Путилов Что, ответ перестал быть ответом? ;)